# Filter drop down list option for grouped_collection_select

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is not a homework. I am doing this to boost my RoR skills.

I have both `Manufacturer` and `Model` entity. I have all the relationship setup correctly and user has to choose `Manufacturer` before choosing `Model`. I added more functionalities to my application that I created. Now, I would like to filter out the `name` from the `Model` dropdown list where the `name` contains the word `(Other)`.

Example for `name` attribute in `Model` entity: `F20`, `F10 (Other)`, `E90`.

I would like to filter out the name of the model which contain `(Other)`. SQL Statement would be `Model.where.not("name LIKE ?", "%(Other)%")`. After the `manufacturer` is selected, `F20` and `E90` will be shown. `F10 (Other)` will be excluded since the name contains the word `(Other)`.

This is what I have for the drop down list form.

```
<%= bootstrap_form_tag url: '/quotation/tints/generate' do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.collection_select :manufacturer_id, Manufacturer.order(:name), :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select Manufacturer"} %> 
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.grouped_collection_select :model_id, Manufacturer.order(:name), :models, :name, :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select Model"} %> 
    </div>

    //Some code here that are not related
<% end %>
```

What I have tried:
In my `tints_controller`, this and I have updated my form in order to work with what I have modified.

```
  def quotation
    @listmanufacturer = Manufacturer.order(:name)
    @listmodel = Model.where.not("name LIKE ?", "%(Other)%")
    render 'quotation'
  end
```

My form

```
<%= bootstrap_form_tag url: '/quotation/tints/generate' do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.collection_select :manufacturer_id, @listmanufacturer, :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select Manufacturer"} %> 
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.grouped_collection_select :model_id, @listmanufacturer, @listmodel, :name, :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select Model"} %> 
    </div>

    //Some code here that are not related
<% end %>
```

However, I received an error like `TypeError: nil is not a symbol`. I am unable to modify my `models_controller` since the drop down list is being used a few times in different view. Some views will need the models with the word `(Other)` and some will not require.

`@listmodel` is the part that breaks everything. By replacing `:models` with `@listmodel`, I am hopping to filter out the models name that contain `(Other)`.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Note: Up to this point, my application is working correctly. All relationships are setup correctly in `model` and `routes` are configured.

UPDATE, more logs

```
ActionView::Template::Error (#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Model id: 1, name: "Kancil Old", manufacturer_id: 1, created_at: "2016-08-14 16:12:24", updated_at: "2016-08-14 16:12:24">, #<Model id: 2, name: "Kancil 04", manufacturer_id: 1, created_at: "2016-08-14 16:12:24", updated_at: "2016-08-14 16:12:24">, #<Model id: 3, name: "Kembara", manufacturer_id: 1, created_at: "2016-08-14 16:12:24", updated_at: "2016-08-14 16:12:24">, #<Model id: 4, name: "Kenari", manufacturer_id: 1, created_at: "2016-08-14 16:12:24", updated_at: "2016-08-14 16:12:24">, #<Model id: 5, name: "Kelisa", manufacturer_id: 1, created_at: "2016-08-14 16:12:24", updated_at: "2016-08-14 16:12:24">, #<Model id: 6, name: "Myvi 05", manufacturer_id: 1, created_at: "2016-08-14 16:12:24", updated_at: "2016-08-14 16:12:24">, #<Model id: 7, name: "Rusa", manufacturer_id: 1, created_at: "2016-08-14 16:12:24", updated_at: "2016-08-14 16:12:24">, #<Model id: 8, name: "Viva", manufacturer_id: 1, created_at: "2016-08-14 16:12:24", updated_at: "2016-08-14 16:12:24">, #<Model id: 9, name: "Alza", manufacturer_id: 1, created_at: "2016-08-14 16:12:24", updated_at: "2016-08-14 16:12:24">, #<Model id: 10, name: "Myvi Ii", manufacturer_id: 1, created_at: "2016-08-14 16:12:24", updated_at: "2016-08-14 16:12:24">, ...]> is not a symbol nor a string):
     6:         </div>
     7: 
     8:         <div class="field">
     9:             <%= f.grouped_collection_select :model_id, @listmanufacturer, @listmodel, :name, :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select Model"} %> 
    10:         </div>
    11: 
    12:         <div class="field">

app/views/tints/quotation.html.erb:9:in `block in _app_views_tints_quotation_html_erb__1724914643_132263140'
app/views/tints/quotation.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_tints_quotation_html_erb__1724914643_132263140'
app/controllers/tints_controller.rb:47:in `quotation'
  Rendering C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (9.0ms)
  Rendering C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (5.0ms)
  Rendering C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (539.0ms)
DEPRECATION WARNING: #original_exception is deprecated. Use #cause instead. (called from status_code_with_paginate at C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/will_paginate-3.1.0/lib/will_paginate/railtie.rb:49)
```

Comment: Which line do you get the error on? Please post the stack trace with the error

Comment: My guess: parentheses might be a special character that needs escaping ???

Comment: @TarynEast I don't think so. I use `Model.where.not("name LIKE ?", "%(Other)%")` in the `index.html.erb` and works nicely without escape character.

Comment: @p4sh4 added the error code, I am not sure whether that is the code that you meant.

Comment: In your server logs (eg in `log/development.log`) you will be able to find the listing of everything that goes on in your app... including the error you got (the `type error`) and this should be immediately followed by a big set of 20-30 lines that look like filenames with numbers. That set is called the stacktrace and it shows you exactly which line of code caused the error. It would be helpful to us (and by extension you) to see the top 3-4 lines of that :)

Comment: Looks like `@listmodel` is `nil` in the form, because you don't set it as an instance variable in your `quotation` method. Try `@listmodel = listmodel` instead of just `listmodel`

Comment: Also not sure if you're using the `grouped_collection_select` method correctly - according to the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_collection_select), it can receive only one collection when you supply two. Looks like instead of supplying  `@listmodel` you'd need to create a `models` method in your `Manufacturer` model that would return the relevant models

Comment: @p4sh4 I have changed what you suggested and here is the error log: http://pastebin.com/th7YM8fW I did read the docs before hand and I have the relationship set up correctly. The reason why I create the `@listmodel` is because I am hopping to filter out the name in `model` that contains the word `(Other)`

Comment: Well, the error says that you're supplying a relation where Rails expects a string or a symbol. Even if you have the relationship set up correctly, you're not using the `grouped_collection_select` correctly. Also, please post the stack trace in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my `Manufacturer model`,

```
class Manufacturer < ApplicationRecord
    //Something here
    def listmodel 
        models.where.not("name LIKE ?", "%(Other)%")
    end 
end
```

In my `form`,

```
<%= bootstrap_form_tag url: '/quotation/tints/generate' do |f| %>
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.collection_select :manufacturer_id, Manufacturer.all.order(:name), :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select Manufacturer"} %> 
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <%= f.grouped_collection_select :model_id, Manufacturer.all.order(:name), :listmodel, :name, :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select Model"} %> 
        </div>
        //More code here
<% end %>
```

Now in my drop down list, model with name containing `(Other)` will be excluded.